# Tween - Infinite repeat without starting from the beginning position

Tags: javascript, three.js, tween, gsap

I have a div and I want to move it forever to in the down position, Tween repeat -1 starts from where the element is began to move. I want it to continue like it's a loop.

```
var tlMain = new TimelineMax({repeat:0});
tlMain.to(group.position, 2 , {y: '-=10', ease: Power0.easeNone, repeat:-1});
```

With above timeline it works like:

```
Start: 10
1st  : 10
2nd  : 10
```

So each time it turns,

```
Start: 10
1st  : 0
2nd  : -10
3rd  : -20
```

Is it possible to achieve this with Tween or do I need to do it in my render method primitively?

```
function render(...args) {
    group.position.y -= 10;

    requestAnimationFrame(render(...args))
}
```

Or do I need to setup a for loop to run this infinitely instead of using repeat? (this works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does no work with `.repeat()` since the animation always starts at the original position (and you can't influence this behavior without changing the library). For such a use case, I would animate the object's position manually like demonstrated in your code example. Or if possible, choose are really low `y` value and a long duration. In this way, you can define a single tween.